# Obtener Reviews de una pagina de Facebook

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-api

Actualmente me encuentro desarrollando una pagina web donde mi jefe quiere que se muestren las calificaciones y comentarios que se han realizado en la pagina de Facebook

*https://www.facebook.com/**PAGINA**/reviews/*

Intente hacerlo con **PHP** usando la función `file_get_contents()` para obtener el contenido de la pagina y luego buscar **Solo los comentarios superiores a 3 estrellas**, sin embargo no tome en cuenta que Facebook por seguridad desde el servidor detecta el navegador desde el cual estoy accediendo y por ende no me sirve esta opción.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Facebook cuenta con una Api que pueda ayudarme?, he buscado en la documentación de Facebook Developers pero no la he encontrado ya que son varias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Open Graph API`**

Facebook te pone a disposición su `Open Graph API`. La parte que te interesa es [`Page Ratings` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings)

Para empezar a usar Open Graph podés remitirte a su [guía de uso aquí.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/)

También tienen un [SDK para PHP](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/using-with-sdks#php-sdk). Y puedes ver el repo [aquí.](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk)